# ASP.Net mvc2 ModelStateDictionary Isvalid mocking using Moq

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-2, moq

I am  new to use moq. I am into creating some unit test case to ASP.Net MVC2 project. In one of a controller i have a code,

if( ModelState.IsValid){
  ......
  ......
}

I tried to mock it in my test method in this way..

```
var modelState = new Mock<ModelStateDictionary>();
modelState.Setup(x => x.IsValid).Returns(true);
```

But the problem is all the time i run the test method  `ModelState.Isvalid` returns false.
Problem is I only able to deal with my test project. I am not authorized to make any changes in my ASP.Net mvc2 project. does anyone of you have any idea of doing this? Thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is add a model error to the `ModelState`, like such:

```
var controller = new YourController();
controller.ModelState.AddModelError("An error");
```

with those two lines the `IsValid` should be false.

Comment: Thank you! But i want to make it always true. Do you have any idea why it always return false.

Comment: @user1448197, if you haven't added any model errors it shouldn't be false.